# Minifiying and Caching ASP.NET bundling Razor views sent via controller/action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS. All my angular js templates/views url are actually asp.net's controller/action, where I return a view.

Something like this.

```
public class TemplateController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

here is the response as seen in the chrome dev tools.

[image]

Now here's what I am trying to achieve.

1. Minify this template, that way the size of the template will reduce and since I have a lot of such tempaltes loading all over the app, it will significantly increase the performance.
2. Cache these templates.

How do I go about this ?

Comment: Minify html have very little benefit on performance and in the sample template you posted, it may only save several bytes of file size. I think you should look into gzip the html instead, which is much easier to achieve and also much larger space on performance improvement.

Comment: Mine is not html, its a .cshtml file a razor view which has few server side ifs and else among the few other.

Comment: `.cshtml` only exist on server side. What client see is only rendered html, and of course what's been transferred between server and client is also purely html. I would suggest to first study the basic concept of how asp.net mvc works.

Comment: Regarding cache, [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) is a very good article explaining how to control cache in mvc application.